# Ckeditor is showing a richtextfield in admin?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I am trying to put a html rich text in django admin. I followed the instructions to the tee. however for some reason it is not picking up ? What am I missing?

Here is the settings.py  -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'skoolprofile',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'disqus',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'easy_maps',
    'hitcount',
    'accounts',
    'localflavor',
    'crispy_forms',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'autoslug',
    'storages',
    'compressor',
    'activities',
    'tastypie',
    'ckeditor',
]

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
}
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
```

here is models.py -

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class adalerts(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length =200, null =True, blank=True) 
    description =  RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor', null = True, blank=True)

    schoolid = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank=True)
    schoolname = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
         return "%s - %s - %s" % (unicode(self.schoolid) , unicode(self.city), (unicode(self.schoolname)))
```

here is admin -

```
admin.site.register(adalerts)
```

I did python manage.py collectstatic. I did makemigrations and migrate. yet no luck in admin for field richtextField "description". I still see a textfield.

Comment: Stilll stuck at it why wont admin shw up a rich editor.  any clues anyone?

Comment: open the google chrome developer tools and see what errors show up there

Answer (score 0):

Can you check on the console if the static files are properly getting loaded?
Also try running `collectstatic` once.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."